# Как сделать чтобы при html validation не получать ошибку: Element ul not allowed as child of element ul in this context

Tags: html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы при html validation не получать ошибку:  Element ul not allowed as child of element ul in this context.

Sample Wedding Menu:

```
  <ul>
     <li>Starter</li>
      <li>
      <ul>
     <li>Starter Turtle Soup</li>
     <li>Caesar Salad</li>
      </ul>
      </li>

     <li>Main</li>
     <li>
     <ul>
     <li>Roast Loin of Lamb</li>
     <li>Sea Bass</li>
     <li>Vegetarian Cannelloni</li>
     </ul>
     </li>

     <li>Desert</li> 
     <li>
     <ul>
     <li>Sicilian Fruit Flan</li>
     <li>Creme Brulee</li>
     </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

Но вот, что получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При таком коде я получаю ошибку:  Element ul not allowed as child of element ul in this context.

Comment: добавь разметку в вопрос а не в комментарий, под вопросом есть кнопка "править" которая позволяет отредактировать вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Список второго уровня должен быть вложен в элемент списка первого уровня

```
<ul>
  <li>Starter
    <ul>
      <li>Starter Turtle Soup</li>
      <li>Caesar Salad</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Main
    <ul>
      <li>Roast Loin of Lamb</li>
      <li>Sea Bass</li>
      <li>Vegetarian Cannelloni</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Desert 
    <ul>
      <li>Sicilian Fruit Flan</li>
      <li>Creme Brulee</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так

```html
<ul> <li><div>Sample Wedding Menu: </div></li><ul><li>Starter</li> <ul><li>Starter Turtle Soup</li> <li>Caesar Salad</li> </ul></ul></ul>
```

Comment: Не получается, что нужно

Comment: @EdgarKiljak [получается](http://i.imgur.com/f3HzcGw.png). Маркера первого уровня у подсписка нет. Это вы что-то не привели в вопросе, или пользуетесь странным браузером.

Comment: Исправил сообщение выше

Comment: @EdgarKiljak а, разметка всё объясняет :)